# Using emplacement to construct a vector of matrices of constant size

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a matrix class (the element type is `Y`) that has, along with other constructors, the following constructor:

```
matrixT(
    size_type rows, // The number of rows
    size_type cols  // The number of columns
) :
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<Y>(rows, cols)
{
}
```

(I use boost BLAS for the actual implementation, but that's not relevant here).

I need a `std::vector<matrixT>` of this (for `Y` a `double`), and I know how many elements I need; `n`, say. I also know all the sizes in advance; all have `rows` rows and `cols` columns

I'd like to do something like

`std::vector<matrixT> vec(n, std::emplace(rows, cols))`

as I'd like to avoid taking deep copies of such matrices. My understanding is I can do *something* to force the constructor to be called; which is what `std::emplace(rows, cols)` is there for.

However I can't get the syntax correct. Any ideas? Do I need to use `std::initialiser_list`?

(If my terminology is incorrect then please feel free to let me know, or edit the question).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the link between passing constructor arguments to your vector elements, and avoiding deep copies.

Comment: I don't want to create each matrix then `push_back` them into the vector.

Comment: Give `matrixT` move semantics then it really doesn't matter. Or `vec.emplace_back(rows, cols)` `n` times. I'm not aware of any function `std::emplace`.

Comment: Is my boss telling porkies? I don't want to accept the answer if you can do it on construction.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't see how `move` matters here.  You cannot move one argument to 55 different ones: it **must** copy.  The issue is that `copy` is (at least the OP thinks) slower than direct construction.  I could see this being somewhat of an issue in practice, where direct construction can zero the memory, while copy has to duplicate it.

Comment: @Yakk: I did not suggest moving the arguments; I suggested being able to move a `matrixT`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sure.  Except we end up making n copies of the `matrixT` regardless.  A move saves at most one "copy" (so n+1 vs n) sort of here.  You'll still want `move`, but it doesn't solve the OP's problem?

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, I know. That's why I went on to suggest `emplace_back`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `emplace_n` and `emplace_create_vector`:

```
template<class... Ts,class...Args>
void emplace_n( std::vector<Ts...>& vec, size_t n, Args&&... args ) {
  if (vec.capacity() < vec.size() + n ) {
    vec.reserve( (std::max)(vec.capacity()*3/2, vec.size()+n) );
  }
  for (size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    vec.emplace_back(args...);
  }
  if (n)
    vec.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class...Ts,class...Args>
std::vector<Ts...> emplace_create_vector( size_t n, Args&&... args ) {
  std::vector<Ts...> retval;
  emplace_n( retval, n, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  return retval;
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f53dceda6c971184)

This lets you create an n-element vector via emplacement, instead of copying.

```
std::vector<matrixT> vec = emplace_create_vector<matrixT>(n, rows, cols);
```

and it does so reasonably efficiently.

Every `vector` copy above will be elided by any acceptable C++ compiler, and no copy or move constructor of `matrixT` is called.

Comment: As an aside, `vector` needs an unsafe `emplace_back` and `push_back` where the caller guarantees there is enough capacity to fit the element.  I'm annoyed by the needless performance hit from that check.
  This is not a concern for the original poster to this question: the performance hit is mainly important when working with `int` or other tiny, cheap types.

Comment: Any decent cpu would see no improvment of an unsafe `push_back` in regards to the capacity limit. Because in `emplace_n` the test will ends to always have the same result and CPU branch prediction will hide the cost 100%. And even if not, you are pushing an object that at least allocate a buffer for the matrix and "cost of capacity test < cost of allocation" by a large amount.

Comment: @galop1n Yes, branch prediction will succeed.  But predicted branches are not free: rather, failed branches are extremely expenses.  For matrixes, this is not a concern, I agree: but for cheap objects like `int` it does mean that carefully written hand-crafted `malloc` code can out perform `vector` *in actual experience*.  When I see cases where hand crafted code can out perform C++ `std` code, I try to find ways to make the `std` code match or exceed the hand crafted code.  In this case (`vector<int>`), the `push_back`/`emplace_back` checks end up being noticable overhead.

Comment: True, but how many time did you found a use of `vector<int>`, initialized to a given size and never use any action that may resize the array. Pay only for what you need, not what you may use. The later example is fulfilled with a `pair<unique_ptr<int[]>,size_t` + some  convenience wrapping into a runtime fixed size at construction array object.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for `std::vector` to have such a constructor.

It already provides a method called `emplace_back`. The arguments of `emplace_back` should match the arguments of one of your constructors.

`vec.emplace_back(rows, cols)` called `n` times will achieve what you want without taking a deep copy of the matrix. You could even `reserve` vector storage in advance.

(`std::initializer` list - note the spelling - is used for *brace initialisation*; a different topic).

Comment: There is no need for an `emplace_n`?  I dunno, it would seem to me to have some utility.

Comment: a generic emplace_n is not simple to design, how do you want to deal with a constructor that take a rvalue argument to steal the content for example ?